# How to convert json data from single key to csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to convert some data from a JSON file to csv. The data from the JSON file that I need exists in a single key.

I have separated the data from that key using the code below. This gives me the data in the following format:

```
[['/s/case/50034000013ZPEoAAO$#@$00192169', 'Unable to add authentication', 'Anypoint Studio', 'Other', '7.1.3', '/s/contact/00334000023cIUYAA2$#@$Paul S', '05-31-2018 22:07', '09-27-2018 05:46', 'S4'], ['/s/case/50034000014dk7mAAA$#@$00195409', 'Connect Virtual Private Circuit - VPC-Pre-Prod 198.18.12.0/23', 'Anypoint Platform', 'CloudHub', '', '/s/contact/00334000023ZzOSAA0$#@$James G', '07-16-2018 15:59', '07-22-2018 14:42', 'S4']
```

I want to separate the data so that everything contained in a square bracket is returned as a single row in my CSV file (the data is a lot longer than above, many more square brackets).

```
import json

json_data = json.load(open('sample_response.txt'))

for x in json_data['actions']:
    data = x['returnValue']
```

Comment: probably you need only use `writerows(data)` to write all in separated rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `writerows(data)` to save it

```
import csv

data = [
    ['/s/case/50034000013ZPEoAAO$#@$00192169', 'Unable to add authentication', 'Anypoint Studio', 'Other', '7.1.3', '/s/contact/00334000023cIUYAA2$#@$Paul S', '05-31-2018 22:07', '09-27-2018 05:46', 'S4'],
    ['/s/case/50034000014dk7mAAA$#@$00195409', 'Connect Virtual Private Circuit - VPC-Pre-Prod 198.18.12.0/23', 'Anypoint Platform', 'CloudHub', '', '/s/contact/00334000023ZzOSAA0$#@$James G', '07-16-2018 15:59', '07-22-2018 14:42', 'S4']
    # more rows
]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as fh:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fh)
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
```